# Issues with Flexslider custom arrows

Tags: css, wordpress, flexslider

Site - http://test06.menchasha.ru/.
I have added custom image for Flexslider right arrow (a.flex-next).
But custom arrows are shown several times (as much as there are Posts).

What should I correct?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flexslider arrows are background images on the .flex-next anchor element. Just set background-repeat: no-repeat; on a.flex-next.

```
a.flex-next {
    background-image: url(wp-content/themes/wp-theme/images/slider-top-pagination.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```